# Condition logic after getting user data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am still learning php so need some help with this.  I know where to modify and insert code snippet but I'm having a hard time writing the code.

I am using a plugin called Userpro and I want to display different content based on user profile's role I am viewing (not the logged in user).  So with userpro_profile_data('role', $user_id) I am able to get the role but I have no idea where to continue from there .. I am thinking of using if else logic like

```
if (role=='customer')
//Do something
else
//Do something else ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you have there is fine. You could do:

```
$role = userpro_profile_data('role', $user_id);

if($role == 'customer')
{
    echo 'Customer';
    // Show Shop Page
}
elseif($role == 'staff')
{
    echo 'Staff';
    // .. show staff page
}
else
{
    echo $role;
    // is not staff or customer
}
```

You could even use a case statement depending on how many roles you have. Your doing fine!

Comment: Thanks!  Good to know I am on the right track.  Your code snippet works perfectly.